# Sticky Navbar variable size changing scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I've got a sticky navbar at the top of my page which has a logo.

When the page scrolls the logo changes to be a bit smaller. This causes a change in the page's Y scroll position. When it gets to a certain point where the scroll threshold is, it is stuck between two positions as the height of the document changes forcing both breakpoints to be continually triggered. (logo flickers between two sizes)

An example of this would be you scroll to say position 100 then the navbar size changes to 59 due to the scroll, then it goes back up to 100 and repeats.

CSS classes are tailwind.

JavaScript doing the operation is below, pretty straight forward.

What are some options of tackling this?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => scrollFunction());

const navLogo = document.querySelector('.navlogo');

function scrollFunction() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
                        navLogo.classList.remove('w-56');
                        navLogo.classList.add('w-36');
                } else {
                        navLogo.classList.add('w-56');
                        navLogo.classList.remove('w-36');
                }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Your requirements may make this a non-starter, but taking your nav bar out of the normal document flow with `position: fixed;` for example, and adding some padding at the top of your page for when you're scrolled to the top is a good way to stop the popping you're describing.

Comment: @LyndenNoye yeah I was thinking that, was trying to avoid a fair bit of padding at the top of the page but it might be unavoidable.

Comment: When you say your navbar is "sticky", do you mean `position: sticky;`? Wrapping your navbar with another element that has a fixed height (the max size caused by the large logo) with a transparent background, and making that your sticky element, should also do the same thing. Now your actual navbar will be able to resize, without also changing the height of the document.

Comment: @LyndenNoye You're a absolute champion, Works a treat. Makes a lot of sense in retrospect. Make that your answer and I'll give you the credit you deserve.

Comment: you're most welcome my dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say your nav bar is "sticky", do you mean `position: sticky;`?

Wrapping your nav bar with another element that has a fixed height (the max size caused by the large logo), and making that your sticky element, should also do the same thing. Now your actual nav bar will be able to resize, without also changing the height of the document.